# Get a React Component name auto suggested in IDE

Tags: reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code, webstorm, es6-modules

I am able to do below import statement for using an exported commonly shared React Component from package `my-shared-dependency` in second package `my-main-app`. Both are in TypeScript. I am able to get Type and Props warnings and `tsc` failures for violating the usage of `MySharedDependentComponent`.

`import {MySharedDependentComponent} from 'my-shared-dependency'`

Now my question is the IDE (VS Code or Webstorm) does not auto suggest that an importable component is available as I type `<MyShared...`. Nor does it seem to auto add the import statement.

Once I add the import statement manually, I can click to be taken to the `index.d.ts` of the dependency inside node modules. :)

How do I show IDE it was available for import ?